# paypal php credit card payment returns 401

Tags: php, paypal, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to make credit card payment via paypal REST API services, I can grab access token, but every time try to make a credit card payment I get 401.

My sample works perfect on .NET but not on PHP. Please advice

```
$json = '{"intent":"sale","redirect_urls":{"return_url":"","cancel_url":""},"payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"number":"4417119669820331","type":"visa","expire_month":11,"expire_year":2018,"cvv2":"874","first_name":"Betsy","last_name":"Buyer","billing_address":{"line1":"111 First Street","city":"Saratoga","state":"CA","postal_code":"95070","country_code":"US"}}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"200","currency":"USD"},"description":"Credit Card Payment - $200"}]}';

$Url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment";
$AccessToken = GetAccessToken();
echo "Bearer ".$AccessToken;
echo "<br><br>";
$headers = array("Authorization" => "Bearer ".$AccessToken, "Content-Type" => "text/json", "Content-length" =>strlen($json));

$handle = curl_init($Url);


curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);   
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response   = curl_exec($handle);
$info = curl_getinfo($handle);
$error= curl_error ( $handle );
curl_close($handle);

var_dump($info);
echo "<br><br>";
var_dump($error);
echo "<br><br>";
var_dump($response);
```

full sample here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3517813/index.php

Comment: You may want to utilize the PHP SDK for REST available at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/ It will save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to process by changing the $headers line to:

$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $AccessToken);

Comment: This is unbelievable, it worked. Is there any reason why header ordering matters in php and doesn't matters in .NET?

Comment: I am getting the same error in java. When I restart the server new access token gets generated.